# Red Black Tree deletion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, red-black-tree

From "Introduction to Algorithms 2nd edition" I got this deletion algorithm:

```
/*
    RB-DELETE(T, z)
    1 if left[z] = nil[T] or right[z] = nil[T]
    2    then y ← z
    3    else y ← TREE-SUCCESSOR(z)
    4 if left[y] ≠ nil[T]
    5    then x ← left[y]
    6    else x ← right[y]
    7 p[x] ← p[y]
    8 if p[y] = nil[T]
    9    then root[T] ← x
    10    else if y = left[p[y]]
    11            then left[p[y]] ← x
    12            else right[p[y]] ← x
    13 if y != z
    14    then key[z] ← key[y]
    15         copy y's satellite data into z
    16 if color[y] = BLACK
    17    then RB-DELETE-FIXUP(T, x)
    18 return y
    */
```

Now few problems with this algorithm, one main problem is that if you try to build tree ( you can do it [here](http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/RedBlack/redblack.html)) with nodes 1,2,3,4,5,6 (placed in this order), and then delete node 2, lines 4,5 and 6 of this algorithm returns nullptr (x == nullptr). Can anyone help me with this?

Here are the helper algorithms (from same book):

```
TREE-SUCCESSOR(x)
1  if right[x] ≠ NIL
2      then return TREE-MINIMUM (right[x])
3  y ← p[x]
4  while y ≠ NIL and x = right[y]
5      do x ← y
6         y ← p[y]
7  return y

 TREE-MINIMUM (x)
1  while left[x] ≠ NIL
2      do x ← left[x]
3  return x

 RB-DELETE-FIXUP(T, x)
 1 while x ≠ root[T] and color[x] = BLACK
 2     do if x = left[p[x]]
 3           then w ← right[p[x]]
 4                if color[w] = RED
 5                   then color[w] ← BLACK                        ▹  Case 1
 6                        color[p[x]] ← RED                       ▹  Case 1
 7                        LEFT-ROTATE(T, p[x])                    ▹  Case 1
 8                        w ← right[p[x]]                         ▹  Case 1
 9                if color[left[w]] = BLACK and color[right[w]] = BLACK
10                   then color[w] ← RED                          ▹  Case 2
11                        x p[x]                                  ▹  Case 2
12                   else if color[right[w]] = BLACK
13                           then color[left[w]] ← BLACK          ▹  Case 3
14                                color[w] ← RED                  ▹  Case 3
15                                RIGHT-ROTATE(T, w)              ▹  Case 3
16                                w ← right[p[x]]                 ▹  Case 3
17                         color[w] ← color[p[x]]                 ▹  Case 4
18                         color[p[x]] ← BLACK                    ▹  Case 4
19                         color[right[w]] ← BLACK                ▹  Case 4
20                         LEFT-ROTATE(T, p[x])                   ▹  Case 4
21                         x ← root[T]                            ▹  Case 4
22        else (same as then clause with "right" and "left" exchanged)
23 color[x] ← BLACK

LEFT-ROTATE(T, x)
 1  y ← right[x]            ▹ Set y.
 2  right[x] ← left[y]      ▹ Turn y's left subtree into x's right subtree.
 3  p[left[y]] ← x
 4  p[y] ← p[x]             ▹ Link x's parent to y.
 5  if p[x] = nil[T]
 6     then root[T] ← y
 7     else if x = left[p[x]]
 8             then left[p[x]] ← y
 9             else right[p[x]] ← y
10  left[y] ← x             ▹ Put x on y's left.
11  p[x] ← y


RB-INSERT(T, z)
 1  y ← nil[T]
 2  x ← root[T]
 3  while x ≠ nil[T]
 4      do y ← x
 5         if key[z] < key[x]
 6            then x ← left[x]
 7            else x ← right[x]
 8  p[z] ← y
 9  if y = nil[T]
10     then root[T] ← z
11     else if key[z] < key[y]
12             then left[y] ← z
13             else right[y] ← z
14  left[z] ← nil[T]
15  right[z] ← nil[T]
16  color[z] ← RED
17  RB-INSERT-FIXUP(T, z)

RB-INSERT-FIXUP(T, z)
 1 while color[p[z]] = RED
 2     do if p[z] = left[p[p[z]]]
 3           then y ← right[p[p[z]]]
 4                if color[y] = RED
 5                   then color[p[z]] ← BLACK                    ▹ Case 1
 6                        color[y] ← BLACK                       ▹ Case 1
 7                        color[p[p[z]]] ← RED                   ▹ Case 1
 8                        z ← p[p[z]]                            ▹ Case 1
 9                   else if z = right[p[z]]
10                           then z ← p[z]                       ▹ Case 2
11                                LEFT-ROTATE(T, z)              ▹ Case 2
12                           color[p[z]] ← BLACK                 ▹ Case 3
13                           color[p[p[z]]] ← RED                ▹ Case 3
14                           RIGHT-ROTATE(T, p[p[z]])            ▹ Case 3
15           else (same as then clause
                         with "right" and "left" exchanged)
16 color[root[T]] ← BLACK
```

**IMPLEMENTATION**

```
    enum Color {Black,Red};

    template<class Key>
    struct Node
    {
        Key* key_;
        Color color_;
        Node* parent_;
        Node* left_;
        Node* right_;
        Node(Key k,Node* parent = nullptr, Node* left = nullptr,Node* right = nullptr):key_(new Key[2]),
            color_(Red),
            parent_(parent),
            left_(left),
            right_(right)
        {
            key_[0] = k;
            key_[1] = '\0';
        }
    };

template<class Key>
class Tree
{
    Node<Key>* head_;
    typedef Key* key_pointer;
    typedef Node<Key>* pointer;
    typedef Node<Key> value_type;
public:
    Tree(Key k):head_(new value_type(k))
    {
        head_->color_ = Black;
    }

    ~Tree()
    {
        delete head_;
    }

    pointer root()const
    {
        auto root = head_;
        while (root->parent_)
        {
            root = root->parent_;
        }
        return root;
    }

    void root(pointer root)
    {
        head_ = root;
    }

    pointer parent()const
    {
        return head_->parent_;
    }

    void parent(pointer parent)
    {
        head_->parent_ = parent;
    }

    pointer left()const
    {
        return head_->left_;
    }

    void left(pointer left)
    {
        head_->left_ = left;
    }

    pointer right()const
    {
        return head_->right_;
    }

    void right(pointer right)
    {
        head_->right_ = right;
    }

    key_pointer key()const
    {
        return head_->key_;
    }
};

template<class Tree,class Node>
void left_rotate(Tree* t, Node* x)
{
    auto y = x->right_;
    x->right_ = y->left_;
    if (y->left_)
    {
        y->left_->parent_ = x;
    }
    y->parent_ = x->parent_;
    if (!x->parent_)
    {
        t->root(y);
    }
    else if(x == x->parent_->left_)
    {
        x->parent_->left_ = y;
    }
    else
    {
        x->parent_->right_ = y;
    }
    y->left_ = x;
    x->parent_ = y;
}

template<class Tree,class Node>
void right_rotate(Tree* t, Node* x)
{
    auto y = x->left_;
    x->left_ = y->right_;
    if (y->right_)
    {
        y->right_->parent_ = x;
    }
    y->parent_ = x->parent_;
    if (!x->parent_)
    {
        t->root(y);
    }
    else if(x == x->parent_->right_)
    {
        x->parent_->right_ = y;
    }
    else
    {
        x->parent_->left_ = y;
    }
    y->right_ = x;
    x->parent_ = y;
}


template<class Tree, class Node_Value>
void insert(Tree* t, Node_Value n)
{
    auto z = make_node(n);
    auto x = t->root();
    decltype(z) y = nullptr;
    while(x)
    {
        y = x;
        if (*z->key_ < *x->key_)
        {
            x = x->left_;
        }
        else
        {
            x = x->right_;
        }
    }
    z->parent_ = y;
    if (!y)
    {
        t->root(z);
    }
    else
    {
        if (*z->key_ < *y->key_)
        {
            y->left_ = z;
        }
        else
        {
            y->right_ = z;
        }
    }
    z->left_ = nullptr;
    z->right_ = nullptr;
    z->color_ = Red;
    insert_fix_up(t,z);
}
template<class Tree, class Node>
void insert_fix_up(Tree* t, Node* z)
{
    while (z->parent_->color_ == Red)
    {
        if (z->parent_ == z->parent_->parent_->left_)
        {
            auto y = z->parent_->parent_->right_;

            if (y->color_ == Red)
            {
                z->parent_->color_ = Black;
                y->color_ = Black;
                z->parent_->parent_->color_ = Red;
                z = z->parent_->parent_;
            }
            else if(z == z->parent_->right_)
            {
                z = z->parent_;
                left_rotate(t,z);
            }
            z->parent_->color_ = Black;
            z->parent_->parent_->color_ = Red;
            right_rotate(t,z->parent_->parent_);
        }
        else
        {
            auto y = z->parent_->parent_->left_;

            if (y->color_ == Red)
            {
                z->parent_->color_ = Black;
                y->color_ = Black;
                z->parent_->parent_->color_ = Red;
                z = z->parent_->parent_;
            }
            else if(z == z->parent_->left_)
            {
                z = z->parent_;
                right_rotate(t,z);
            }
            z->parent_->color_ = Black;
            z->parent_->parent_->color_ = Red;
            left_rotate(t,z->parent_->parent_);
        }
    }
    t->root()->color_ = Black;
}

template<class Node>
Node* tree_minimum(Node* x)
{
    while (x->left_)
    {
        x = x->left_;
    }
    return x;
}

template<class Node>
Node* tree_successor(Node* x)
{
    if (x->right_)
    {
        return tree_minimum(x->right_);
    }
    auto y = x->parent_;
    while (y && x == y->right_)
    {
        x = y;
        y = y->parent_;
    }
    return y;
}

template<class Tree, class Node>
Node* rb_delete(Tree* t,Node* z)
{
    Node* x = nullptr;
    Node* y = nullptr;
    if (!z->left_ || !z->right_)
    {
        y = z;
    }
    else
    {
        y = tree_successor(z);
    }
    if (y->left_)
    {
        x = y->left_;
    }
    else
    {
        x = y->right_;
    }
    x->parent_ = y->parent_;
    if (!y->parent_)
    {
        t->root(x);
    }
    else if (y == y->parent_->left_)
    {
        y->parent_->left_ = x;
    }
    else
    {
        y->parent_->right_ = x;
    }
    if (y != z)
    {
        z->key_ = y->key_; 
    }
    if (y->color_ = Black)
    {
        rb_delete_fix_up(t,x);
    }
    return y;
}

template<class Tree, class Node>
void rb_delete_fix_up(Tree*& t,Node*& x)
{
    while (x != t->root() && x->color_ == Black)
    {
        Node* w = nullptr;
        if (x == x->parent_->left_)
        {
            w = x->parent_->right_;
            if (w->color_ == Red)
            {
                w->color_ = Black;
                x->parent_->color_ = Red;
                left_rotate(t,x->parent_);
                w = x->parent_->right_;
            }
            if (w->left_->color_ == Black && w->right_->color_ == Black)
            {
                w->color_ = Red;
                x = x->parent_;
            }
            else if(w->right_->color_ == Black)
            {
                w->left_->color_ = Black;
                w->color_ = Red;
                right_rotate(t,w);
                w = x->parent_->right_;
            }
            w->color_ = x->parent_->color_;
            x->parent_->color_ = Black;
            w->right_->color_ = Black;
            left_rotate(t,x->parent_);
            x = t->root();
        }
        else
        {
                w = x->parent_->left_;
            if (w->color_ == Red)
            {
                w->color_ = Black;
                x->parent_->color_ = Red;
                right_rotate(t,x->parent_);
                w = x->parent_->left_;
            }
            if (w->right_->color_ == Black && w->left_->color_ == Black)
            {
                w->color_ = Red;
                x = x->parent_;
            }
            else if(w->left_->color_ == Black)
            {
                w->right_->color_ = Black;
                w->color_ = Red;
                left_rotate(t,w);
                w = x->parent_->left_;
            }
            w->color_ = x->parent_->color_;
            x->parent_->color_ = Black;
            w->left_->color_ = Black;
            right_rotate(t,x->parent_);
            x = t->root();
        }

    }
    x->color_ = Black;
}
template<class Key>
Node<Key>* make_node(Key k)
{
    return new Node<Key>(k);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    auto t = new Tree<int>(1);
    insert(t,2);
    insert(t,3);
    insert(t,4);
    insert(t,5);
    insert(t,6);
    rb_delete(t,t->left());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked if your problem is listed here: http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~thc/clrs-2e-bugs/bugs.php ?

Comment: Can we see your actual implementation?

Comment: There might be something wrong with the implementation. RBTrees are pretty solid and well-tested. Especially with a well-known case like inserting a sorted list of items.

Comment: @Patric and Nico no problem give me 5 min and I will present you with all those algorithms implemented. As far as I'm concerded neither insertion nor deletion work properly (for tree built in this order:1,2,3,4,5,6).

Comment: I doubt that, since the algorithm works correctly at the link you posted. Post a comment when you add your implementation, so that we can take a look at your code. I would guess that you are trying to assign a value to X when you have not declared the variable.

Comment: @Patric I've just uploaded my implementation

Comment: @Patric I'm not entirely sure that the link I've posted used this **exact** algorithm

Comment: @smallB so, according to the algorithm, x should become the node '1', but you are saying that nothing gets assigned to x?

Comment: @Patric I do not know what x should become, I just know that those algorithms (insert and delete) are screwed up. And what's even more interesting I found 3rd edition of this book and surprise surprise!!! those algorithms still don't work. What a f..ing liberty!!!

Comment: @Patric I just wonder if anyone from those people ever tried to build from a scratch a red black tree using those algorithms?

Comment: @smallB I would try doing some actual debugging before I starting blaming people much smarter than the both of us. Not only have these algorithms been _proved_ correct, they have also been implemented countless times. I have implemented these algorithms myself, and trust me, they do work. I understand that debugging can be frustrating, but its what you signed up for.

Comment: @Patric are you willing to share your implementation? And did you actually implemented them "word by word" from this particular book?

Comment: @Patric and one more thought, what debugging? If provided that I didn't make any typos and implemented their algorithm "word by word" why would I need to debug it? Shouldn't it work especially as if you're saying they have been proven and implemented countless times? And my opinion? Yes, they've been proven but haven't been tested. Bit of a difference.

Comment: @Patric so what about your implementation? Did you used exactly those algorithms presented in this book, without changing anything?

Comment: @smallB Yes I did. I don't have the implementation anymore, so I would just try debugging a little. As antonakos has demonstrated, there are issues with your code. Once again, if I were you I would put the blame on myself before jumping to conclusion about the incorrectness of well known and tested algorithms.

Comment: @Patric as I've proved it in my code if you don't do as antonakos said (about is_red) or other form of checking if y != nullptr the **code will never work correctly**.

Comment: @Patric and if you did word by word what this pseudocode says then your implementation has/had bugs. As simple as that.

Comment: @smallB let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1614/discussion-between-patrick-and-smallb)

Answer (score 9):

For a version of rb-tree without sentinels the delete operation implementation is as follows:

```
SWRedBlackNode delete(SWRedBlackTree tree, SWRedBlackNode node) {
    SWRedBlackNode y;
    if (node._left == null || node._right == null) {
        y = node;
    } else {
        y = node.getSuccessor();
    }

    SWRedBlackNode x;
    if (y._left != null) {
        x = y._left;
    } else {
        x = y._right;
    }
    if (x != null) {
        x._parent = y._parent;
    }
    SWRedBlackNode xParent = y._parent;

    boolean yIsLeft = false;
    if (y._parent == null) {
        tree._root = x;
    } else if (y == y._parent._left) {
        y._parent._left = x;
        yIsLeft = true;
    } else {
        y._parent._right = x;
        yIsLeft = false;
    }

    if (y != node) {
        node._value = y._value;
    }

    if (!y._isRed) {
        deleteFixUp(tree, x, xParent, yIsLeft);
    }

    return y;
}

private void deleteFixUp(SWRedBlackTree tree, SWRedBlackNode node, SWRedBlackNode nodeParent, boolean nodeIsLeft) {
    while (node != tree._root && isBlack(node)) {
        SWRedBlackNode w;
        if (nodeIsLeft) {
            w = nodeParent._right;
            if (isRed(w)) {
                w._isRed = false;
                nodeParent._isRed = true;
                leftRotate(tree, nodeParent);
                w = nodeParent._right;
            }

            if (isBlack(w._left) && isBlack(w._right)) {
                w._isRed = true;
                node = nodeParent;
                nodeParent = node._parent;
                nodeIsLeft = (node == nodeParent._left);
            } else {
                if (isBlack(w._right)) {
                    w._left._isRed = false;
                    w._isRed = true;
                    rightRotate(tree, w);
                    w = nodeParent._right;
                }

                w._isRed = nodeParent._isRed;
                nodeParent._isRed = false;
                if (w._right != null) {
                    w._right._isRed = false;
                }
                leftRotate(tree, nodeParent);
                node = tree._root;
                nodeParent = null;
            }
        } else { /* nodeIsLeft == false */
            w = nodeParent._left;
            if (isRed(w)) {
                w._isRed = false;
                nodeParent._isRed = true;
                rightRotate(tree, nodeParent);
                w = nodeParent._left;
            }

            if (isBlack(w._right) && isBlack(w._left)) {
                w._isRed = true;
                node = nodeParent;
                nodeParent = node._parent;
                nodeIsLeft = (node == nodeParent._left);
            } else {
                if (isBlack(w._left)) {
                    w._right._isRed = false;
                    w._isRed = true;
                    leftRotate(tree, w);
                    w = nodeParent._left;
                }

                w._isRed = nodeParent._isRed;
                nodeParent._isRed = false;
                if (w._left != null) {
                    w._left._isRed = false;
                }
                rightRotate(tree, nodeParent);
                node = tree._root;
                nodeParent = null;
            }
        }
    }

    node._isRed = false;
}
```

It's in Java but can easily be ported to any language.

The following code is different in respect to your implementation:

Nesting here:

```
            } else {
                if (isBlack(w._right)) {
```

and here:

```
            } else {
                if (isBlack(w._left)) {
```

Without-sentinel stuff here:

```
    if (x != null) {
        x._parent = y._parent;
    }
    SWRedBlackNode xParent = y._parent;

    boolean yIsLeft = false;
    if (y._parent == null) {
        tree._root = x;
    } else if (y == y._parent._left) {
        y._parent._left = x;
        yIsLeft = true;
    } else {
        y._parent._right = x;
        yIsLeft = false;
    }
```

then here:

```
        deleteFixUp(tree, x, xParent, yIsLeft);
```

and in `deleteFixUp()` - just look for usage of `nodeParent` and `nodeIsLeft`, and finally at this place:

```
                if (w._right != null) {
                    w._right._isRed = false;
                }
```

and this:

```
                if (w._left != null) {
                    w._left._isRed = false;
                }
```

Comment: instead of (node == nodeParent._left), should be (nodeParent != null && node == nodeParent._left)

Otherwise you can get a nullpointer exception when you reach the root node.

Besides for that, this is an excellent solution for delete/delete-fixup without sentinels

Comment: This is missing a null test somewhere (could change final line of `deleteFixUp` to `if (node != null) node._isRed = false`; or could change `if (!y._isRed) { deleteFixUp(tree, x, xParent, yIsLeft);}` to `if (!y._isRed && tree._root != null) { deleteFixUp(tree, x, xParent, yIsLeft);}`) because it gives a NullPointerException when the tree is a single black node and you delete it.

Comment: @trog Where can I find the rest of this code? Namely, the rotate left, right, get getSuccessor, etc...

Answer (score 1):

The color of a `Nil` node is defined to be black. The code contains statements such as

```
if (y->color_ == Red)
```

that will crash if `y` is a `nullptr`. If you replace all such comparisons with calls to safe `is_red()` and `is_black()` functions that check for `Nil` nodes, then some of the crashes go away.

The nesting here

```
        else if(z == z->parent_->right_)
        {
            z = z->parent_;
            left_rotate(t,z);
        }
        z->parent_->color_ = Black;
        z->parent_->parent_->color_ = Red;
        right_rotate(t,z->parent_->parent_);
```

doesn't match the nesting here:

```
 9                   else if z = right[p[z]]
10                           then z ← p[z]         
11                                LEFT-ROTATE(T, z)
12                           color[p[z]] ← BLACK   
13                           color[p[p[z]]] ← RED  
14                           RIGHT-ROTATE(T, p[p[z]])
```

Other things may need debugging too, but I don't think that CLR will be to blame.

Comment: thanks for your answer, about the nesting, how else should it be? Inside of the else if?

Comment: and about is_red() || is_black()? And what am I supposed to do if it is nullptr? Skip just the line where the null variable is mentioned? Skip whole block? That's what pisses me off, 3rd edition of this book and yet you cannot build tree based on their algorithms. Pathetic.

Comment: and the whole procedure delete? It's screwed up. Try to built tree 1,2,3,4,5,6 in that order and then delete node 1.

Comment: @smallB `is_red()` should return false on `nullptr` and `is_black()` should return true. The nesting should be like `else { if (...) { ... } ... }`.

Comment: thanks for your comment on nesting. That works now. But delete is screwed up. Try it and you'll see.